# Cannot find module 'graphql/tsutils/Maybe' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: graphql, nestjs

This problem has never existed, no conditions have changed
node_modules/@apollo/federation/dist/composition/utils.d.ts:3:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graphql/tsutils/Maybe' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import Maybe from 'graphql/tsutils/Maybe';

```
@nestjs/graphql": "^7.3.7",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.13.1",
"graphql": "^15.1.0",
"graphql-tools": "^5.0.0",
"graphql-type-json": "^0.3.1",
"@types/graphql": "^14.5.0"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found solution my graphql version dont matching with @types/graphql

```
 graphql: ^15.1.0
 @types/graphql: ^14.5.0
```

if there are people who have such a problem just matched your graphql versions with types like

```
graphql: ^14.5.0
@types/graphql: ^14.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that **graphql/tsutils/Maybe.d.ts** is removed with the graphql version **15.1.0**.